# mockito.AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg() for overloaded methods

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a problem with `returnsFirstArg` for overloaded methods, where the `firstArg` is not nessessarily the same type as the return type.

1. I want both methods to return the string value of the first argument.
2. Even better they always return the value of `key`

Is there anyway to achieve this and get these Tests green?

This is a minimum NOT working example, in real live Translator is more complex and can't be modified.

```java
package test;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg;

import java.util.Locale;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TranslatorTest {

    private class Translator {

        String getText(final String key) {
            return "translated " + key;
        }

        String getText(final Locale locale, final String key) {
            return "translated " + key + " for locale " + locale;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test_withoutToString() throws Exception {
        final String key = "com.stackoverflow.translator.label";
        Translator translator = mock(Translator.class,  returnsFirstArg());

        assertThat(translator.getText(key), is(key));

        final Locale locale = new Locale("en_GB"); // java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Locale cannot be cast to java.lang.String
        assertThat(translator.getText(locale, key), is(key));
    }

    @Test
    public void test_withToString() throws Exception {
        final String key = "com.stackoverflow.translator.label";
        Translator translator = mock(Translator.class,  returnsFirstArg().toString());

        assertThat(translator.getText(key), is(key));
        /*
         * java.lang.AssertionError:
         *  Expected: is "com.stackoverflow.translator.label"
         *  but: was null
         */

        final Locale locale = new Locale("en_GB");
        assertThat(translator.getText(locale, key), is(key));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't bend over backwards to try to define some generic default behavior when creating the mock object. You have two different methods, and could just specify two different behaviors explicitly:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    translator = mock(Translator.class);
    when(translator.getText(any(), any()))
        .thenAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.returnsSecondArg());
    when(translator.getText(any()))
        .thenAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg());
}
```

**EDIT:**

Addressing the added/clarified requirement in the comments could be problematic, unless you have a good way to recognize argument you want to return.

Assuming you can use some straight-forward logic, like returning the first string argument, you could implement your own [`Answer`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.12.0/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html):

```
Answer<Object> returnsFirstString =
        invocationOnMock -> Arrays.stream(invocationOnMock.getArguments())
                .filter(String.class::isInstance)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);

translator = mock(Translator.class, returnsFirstString);
```

This can, of course, be refined with some different logic like applying to `getText` methods only, etc.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I already thought about that. But as this is just a minimum example, in real live there are more than two overloaded methods - so I thought there is a better way than mock every method separatly.

Comment: @ppasler If you can define the logic you're trying to mock, you could implement your own `Answer`. See my edited answer for an example.

Comment: Thanks for the extended answer. I finally came to the desicion, that I'll mock every overloaded method. A custom Answer adds no value in this case.